# Check if this cryptosystem is safe

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Let $G$ be any group where group operations, as well as finding the inverse of an
element, can be performed quickly, but the discrete log problem is difficult. Consider
the following cryptosystem:

1. Alice chooses an element $g ∈ G$, a message $m ∈ G$, and an integer $k_A$.
2. Alice computes $s = mg^{k_A}$ and sends $s$ to Bob.
3. Bob chooses an integer $k_B$, computes $t = sg^{k_B}$ , and sends Alice $t$.
4. Alice computes $u = tg^{−k_A} = mg^{k_B}$ and sends $u$ to Bob.
5. Bob computes $ug^{−k_B} = m$ and recovers the message.

Is this cryptosystem safe?
I've noticed that Eve has $s$, $t$, and $u$ 
and that they are all divisible by m. Does this mean it's not safe? Or what am I missing?

Help is appreciated

Comment: This system in addition of being insecure as pointed by cpast, is rather strange. In fact it look like a PK cryptosystem but it is not one, by the simple reason that there are no construction based on a trapdoor one way function. to Break as cpast show it, it suffice also to listen the transaction and compute $u\times s\times t^{-1}=m$. 
Another observation, in a group structure, any element can be divided by any other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is extremely insecure. The discrete log is a red herring -- nowhere in the problem is the difficulty of discrete log relevant, because neither party ever uses their knowledge of their private exponent (computing $g^{-k}$ given $g^{k}$ does *not* require knowledge of $k$, so if inverses are fast to find, knowing one gives you the other quickly). That means we can ignore the exponentiation; all you have is Alice picking $a\in G$ and Bob picking $b\in G$, so $s=ma$, then $t=mab=sb$, then $u=ta^{-1}=mb$. Eve intercepts $s,t,u$, and computes $s^{-1}$, then $s^{-1}t=b$, then $b^{-1}$, then $ub^{-1}=m$. The issue isn't really that they're all divisible by $m$, it's that you rely on keeping $a$ and $b$ private but then send $s$ and $sb$ over a public channel (which means an attacker can easily recover $b$ and thus $m$).

In actual ElGamal, you actually *use* your private exponent. Instead of having to keep $g^{k_A}$ and $g^{k_B}$ secret, you rely on the fact that Alice (who knows $g^{k_B}$ and $k_A$) can compute $g^{k_Ak_B}$ while an attacker cannot. To use the security of discrete log, you have to do something that's easy for someone knowing the exponent but difficult for someone else; finding the inverse is not that something.